# Increase perfomance when fetching data from remote database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, performance, remote-server

I use the following code to connect with a remote(over internet) mysql database and to fill a datagrid with the returned result. This works fine, but it takes some time to fill up the grid when there are around 200 or more rows available.
I want to know whether there is any adjustments I should do to make the process more speed or what would be the most suitable thing i should to make the things more speedy.

current coding

```
connection = new MySqlConnection(db_con_s);
connection.Open();
sql = connection.CreateCommand();
sql.CommandTimeout = 5000;
sql.CommandText = my_query;
MySqlDataReader Reader1 = sql.ExecuteReader();

if (Reader1 != null && Reader1.HasRows)
{
     while (Reader1.Read())                                    
     {
          cv++;
          dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cv,Reader1.GetString("l_id"), Reader1.GetString("l_code"),...............);
          d1 += Reader1.GetDouble("l_amount");
     }
}
```

Comment: What kind of app is consuming the data?

Comment: can you have paged results? if mysql has support for paging maybe that will help

Comment: @The Sharp Ninja  :: this db is a replicated slave of a locally running small application and this online database is going too use only to view info when main server is not accesible.  i want to display all the loan information of the staff.

Comment: I meant what type of application is it?  WinForms, WPF, ASP.Net?

Comment: winforms. c# .net 4.5

Comment: Don't forget to dispose umanaged resources (connections, readers, etc.) or use `using` statement

Answer (score 2):

Can you do something like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(Reader1);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

And see if that improves the performance?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try with this. Hope sometimes this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Use pagination and fetch 20/50 as per your requirement and populate in your data grid.This will improve the performance.

Also you can improve the query performance by indexing the data on the columns on which you are filtering data.
As you haven't provided SQL query, so all columns in where clause must be indexed

Comment: There is no issue with the query at all. Is there anything other than that. when i execute the query directly on the remote server it only takes less than one sec. to execute the qry.

Comment: Is columns in your table indexed ???I suspect....Also please use pagination to fetch few results if you just need to display data...

Comment: Thanks Naruto. Pagination is really an option. But i will use it if i couldn't speedup the things up to somelevel without that.

Comment: @kumaDK can you please provide query structure that you are using and table structure....As for local and remote DB is concerned...there will be small delay as data is transferred over network...i suspect the issue is due to not proper indexing...

Comment: I ran the same query directly against the same remote DB using a third party DB administration tool and it fetches 200 records within around 1.5 seconds and its acceptable. That means i have no issue with query execution or optimization.